# Is there an r function for holding type 1 and 2 errors constant?

Tags: r, function, statistics

I want to generalize a function for a range of alternative hypothesis (HA) while holding type 1 error (alpha =< 0.05) and type 2 errors (beta =< 0.2) constant while allowing the number of observations (n) to shift to allow for conditions for alpha and beta to be satisfied as HA shifts across the ranges passed. My distribution is binomial. The situation is a coin flip and the null (H0) is that it is a fair coin H0 = 0.5. HA = 0.6 that it is weighted. Here is the r code to identify the number of observations to satisfy a =< 0.05 and B =< 0.2:

```
betafun <- function(n){
  pbinom(qbinom(0.95,n,0.5),n,0.6)}

n <- 150:170
plot(n,betafun(n))

sum(dbinom(90:158,158,0.5))
sum(dbinom(0:89,158,0.6))
```

I want a range of HA from 0.6 to 0.7:

```
x <- seq(from=0.6,to=0.7,len=11)

betafun <- function(n){
      pbinom(qbinom(0.95,n,0.5),n,x)}
```

How do I write a function that will tell me the minimum n need to satisfy a=<0.05 and B =< 0.2 for the range of HA?

Thanks for any help

Comment: Are you familiar with power analysis?

Comment: [Power analysis for binomial data when the null hypothesis is that p=0](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/38439/power-analysis-for-binomial-data-when-the-null-hypothesis-is-that-p-0)